# Undifined method rows for nill:Class when migrating my database using mysql2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Every time i do  rake db:migrate i get an error saying "undefined method "rows" for nill:Class". I am using the mysql2 gem on my windows machine and have installed mysql v-5.5.13. Sqlite3 works very fine when i migrate but mysql does not. it only creates the database and creats the first table but when it wants to finish the migration of the first table i get the error. Any help?

Comment: the code is from My console window. all i did was to install mysql2 gem and change my database.yml to mysql2. then run rake db:migrate

Comment: If you're on Rails 3.0.x you need to use `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.7'` in your Gemfile. You might want to verify that this is the case.

Comment: @coreyward would it work for windows

Comment: Windows is irrelevant here. It's the same gem for either platform.

Comment: @coreyward i tried it out and it is saying checking main in --libmysql...no whit other error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve the problem by:

```
gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include"'
```

JUST to suit your need if you are having the same problem